# Multilingual XML sitemaps when using qTranslate-X

Tags: plugin-qtranslate, sitemap, google-xml-sitemaps

I am taking over a multilingual website that a previous developer left unfinished, and I found that he had used qTranslate-X as a localization plugin, in order to create handle the multilingual part of it.

The problem I find now is how to create a XML sitemap that has all the pages in their different language versions:

- Yoast SEO can generate sitemaps, but it doesn't work with qTranslate-X. The plugin they recommend in order to make both play nice together is this https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-seo-qtranslate-x/, but it hasn't been updated in years and it doesn't work.
- Then there's [Google XML Sitemaps v3 for qTranslate](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-v3-for-qtranslate/), which doesn't work either, in the sense that it generates sitemaps with only one language.

And there are other solutions lying around, but either they don't work, or they are for qTranslate (not qTranslate-X) and don't work anymore.

Has anybody has actually managed to achieve this? (That is: generate a complete multilingual XML sitemap from a multilingual site developed with qTranslate-X).

Comment: I use qTranslate-X and Google XML Sitemaps v3 for qTranslate on a number of sites and there's no problem. Have a look: https://www.pad-fairs.com/paris/sitemap.xml